# using javascript in a rails view when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm a full on newbie at programming. I know what I'd like to do, and believe I have the code I need, but I don't know how to get everything hooked up.

I have this link:

> "color:green;" %>

When it is clicked/pressed, I would like this javascript countdown to be invoked: (it brings up a countdown box)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timeout;
function openInfoDialog() {
  Dialog.info("Test of info panel, it will close <br>in 3s ...",
               {width:250, height:100, showProgress: true});
  timeout=3;
  setTimeout(infoTimeout, 1000)
}

function infoTimeout() {
  timeout--;
  if (timeout >0) {
    Dialog.setInfoMessage("Test of info panel, it will close <br>in " + timeout + "s ...")
    setTimeout(infoTimeout, 1000)
 }
 else
  Dialog.closeInfo()
}
openInfoDialog();

</script>
```

Then, when that box closes, I'd like the page to refresh.  The thing is, I don't know how to call that javascript upon the click, or make a page refresh only one time.

Alternatively, I think I could make things work with this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
<p>
<a href="javascript:timedRefresh(2000)">Refresh this page in 2 seconds</a> |
<a href="javascript:timedRefresh(5000)">Refresh this page in 5 seconds</a>
</p>
</div>
```

But here again I don't quite get how to use this javascript with a rails link.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the link. Assuming you're using jquery (if not you should):

```
<%= link_to 'Start monitoring this room', start_robot_path(@robot), :class => 'some_class %>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_class').click(function(event){
        openInfoDialog();
        return false;       
    })
})

#stylesheet.css
a.some_class{
  color:green
}
```